# Benign zombies who want to cuddle story

Tags: story-identification

I read this in the UK during the COVID lockdown. Some unremembered anthology (I did a lot of reading during that time!)

A guy wakes up and leaves his apartment, as soon as he exits onto the street hordes of zombies charge at him so he squeals in surprise and runs back upstairs, he bolts his door just in time and then he hears more and more banging and thumping on his door - in desperation he rigs up some kind of firebomb and destroys a lot of them on the stairwell.

He then makes a run for it but gets cut off at a junction, he's frantically kicking and punching as they close in around him, finally he's grabbed but not bitten. Instead they're gently stroking his head and hands and making soft cooing noises.

He makes contact (I don't recall how) with other scattered survivors and learns that most of the population died almost simultaneously and that they crave the warmth and vitality of the living as it reminds them of their humanity.

He, together with some young kid, head to another town and there they find some weird shenanigans - a pervy survivor has got some curvaceous female zombies into cheerleader uniforms and harnessed then to a carriage, he parades around the streets while the zombies line the pavements and coo as he passes

I don't remember how it ends